# Sed an XML balise

Tags: sed, xml

Please, I have this xml balise inside my `test.xml` file

```
<ingressAnnotations>nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
  location @custom_503 {
    return 503 &quot;&lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;meta http-equiv=&apos;Content-Type&apos; content=&apos;text/html; charset=UTF-8&apos;&gt; &lt;style&gt;...&lt;/style&gt;&lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt;&lt;img src=&apos;https://www.jenkins.io/images/logos/jenkins-is-the-way/j
enkins-is-the-way.png&apos; width=&apos;200&apos; height=&apos;200&apos; style=&apos;display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;&apos; alt=&apos;jenkins&apos;&gt;&lt;center&gt;&lt;h2&gt;Jenkins is sleeping, please go to jenkins.betclic.net and click your Maste
r link to wake him up. It will be available in a few minutes. This is the wait !!!&lt;/h2&gt;&lt;/center&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;&quot;;
  }
  error_page 503 @custom_503;</ingressAnnotations>
```

I have to parse my file and remove the content. Something like that:

```
<ingressAnnotations></ingressAnnotations>
```

How can I do that by sed please ?
I'm trying this:

```
sed -i 's/<ingressAnnotations>*<\/ingressAnnotations>/<ingressAnnotations><\/ingressAnnotations>/g' test.xml
```

But it does not work !

Comment: "_It does not work_" - What did you expect to happen? What actually happens? Did you get any error messages? Don't use `-i` while you're testing.

Comment: please do not try to parse XML with regular expression tools. **XML is not a regular language, and cannot reliably be parsed with them.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an XML parser to parse and edit your file. This command matches the `<ingressAnnonations/>` tag anywhere and everywhere in your document and removes all its content:

```
xmlstarlet edit --update '//ingressAnnotations' --value '' test.xml
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ingressAnnotations/>
```

Include the `--inplace` parameter (i.e. `xmlstarlet edit --inplace --update …`) to edit the file in place once you are sure the transformation works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy, but works:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/<ingressAnnotations>/{p; :a; N; /<\/ingressAnnotations>/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p' \
FILENAME | sed -e 's/>.*/>/g' -e 's/.*<\//<\//g'
```

The above gives:

```
<ingressAnnotations>
</ingressAnnotations>
```

**EDITED.**

To remove newline between the patterns, add `| sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'` pipe, so:

```bsh
$ sed -n '/<ingressAnnotations>/{p; :a; N; /<\/ingressAnnotations>/!ba; s/.*\n//}; p' \
FILENAME \
| sed -e 's/>.*/>/g' -e 's/.*<\//<\//g' \
| sed -e :a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
```

Comment: No, it will work with the above pattern, so if there are new lines involved.

Comment: @roaima, right about -i, that would have to be redirected to a file

Comment: `printf "<root>\n<ingressAnnotations>nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |\n  location @custom_503 { }\n  error_page 503 @custom_503;</ingressAnnotations>\n<ingressAnnotations>boo</ingressAnnotations>\n<ingressAnnotations>\nmultiline\ncomments\n</ingressAnnotations>\n</root>\n"` generates valid XML that fails your transformations. I don't know how plausible it is in the OP's context though. The point is that `sed` on XML is fragile